Changing my LAN IPv4 to DHCP makes opnsense unreachable on hetzner
I following a tutorial on a blog about opensense.
I have a client server and opnsense server. I want the client server to use opnsense for its network and have access to public network through the opnsense.
I installed opnsense in Hetzner. I use vtnet0 as wan but after installation and I added vtnet1 to interfaces as LAN then changed the IPv4 to DHCP and apply changes, opnsense become unreachable.
I am following this tutorial
https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/how-to-route-cloudserver-over-private-network-using-pfsense-and-hcnetworks#step-3---set-up-the-client-server
I don't know if this is because this is opnsense
Details of my settings:
Network is 10.0.0.0/16
route in Hetzner cloud network subnet is 0.0.0.0/0 to 10.0.0.2
Opnsense server 10.0.0.2
Client server 10.0.0.3


I think that OpnSense disables web access on the WAN interface when you enable the LAN interface, unless you explicitly enable WAN access to the web interface in the firewall rules. I'm not in a place where I can double-check that right now though.
